# not able to access $_POST on backend profile update

Tags: php, plugin-development, forms, user-meta

I have some meta fields for the users on my website, but I can't access to the `$_POST` variables after de update. 
The curious thing is that after the update, if I comment the conditional, the meta is updated properly with the `$_POST` content, but I am not able to use conditionals using `$_POST` because I have an error,

> Undefined index: gdpr_data_consent_field

I can see all the `$_POST` data in `user-edit.php`, but as the form is in the url `/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=13&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php` I am not able to have access to it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function privacity_user_profile_fields() {
    global $user_id;

    if ($_POST['gdpr_data_consent_field'] == 'true' ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', 'true' );
        echo 'IS TRUE';
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', 'false' );
        echo 'IS FALSE';
    }

    $data_consent = get_user_meta($user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', true);
    $data_consent_text = 'He leído y entendido el cómo se tratarán los datos introducidos durante el registro en esta web.';
?>

<h2 id="privacity">Opciones de privacidad</h2>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_data_consent_field" id="data-consent-field" value="true" <?php echo ($data_consent == 'true') ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
    <label for="data-consent-field"><?php echo $data_consent_text; ?></label>
</p>
<?php 
}
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'privacity_user_profile_fields');
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'privacity_user_profile_fields' );
?>
```

I can't sleep!! What I'm doing wrong? 
A lot of thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake.
I was hooking twice the same code, one in the 'edit_user_profile' and other in 'edit_user_profile_update'.
I have separated the display code from de update code and now it works like have to:

```
<?php
function privacity_user_profile_fields() {
    global $user_id;
    $data_consent = get_user_meta($user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', true);
    $data_consent_text = 'He leído y entendido el cómo se tratarán los datos 
      introducidos durante el registro en esta web.';
    ?>

    <h2 id="privacity">Opciones de privacidad</h2>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_data_consent_field" id="data-consent-field" value="true" <?php echo ($data_consent == 'true') ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
        <label for="data-consent-field"><?php echo $data_consent_text; ?></label>
    </p>
    <?php 
}
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'privacity_user_profile_fields');

function privacity_user_profile_update() {
    global $user_id;
    if ($_POST['gdpr_data_consent_field'] == 'true' ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', 'true' );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gdpr_user_register_consent', 'false' );
    }
}
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'privacity_user_profile_update' );
?>
```